# Storing time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to store a date 3 months from the current date and put it into `current_user.expiry_date`.

`current_user.expiry_date = Date.today + 3.months`

I'm new to doing dates but is this sufficient? `expiry_date` is of data type `date`. This would give an expiry date 3 months after this attribute is set. Anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

That looks fine to me. It should give you the date 3 months from now.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'active_support/all'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Date.today + 3.months
=> Mon, 21 Nov 2016
irb(main):003:0> (Date.today + 3.months).class
=> Date
```

Comment: You could also write this as `current_user.expiry_date = 3.months.from_now`